# Cannot load relative file in Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.6

Files are organized as follows:

```
- myScriptProject
  - solutions.ru
  - main.ru
```

solution.ru

```
def test_function
  puts 'Hello World'
end
```

main.rb

```
#!/Users/myusername/.rbenv/shims/ruby

require './solution' # or require_relative 'solution'

test_function
```

I was trying to run the scripts:

```
$ cd myScriptProject/
$ ruby main.ru
```

Then I got an LoadError message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from test.ru:3:in `<main>'
        1: from /Users/myusername/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/myusername/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./solution (LoadError)
```

What could be the issue in this case?

By the way, my Ruby environment is managed by rbenv.

```
$ which ruby
$ /Users/myusername/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's script extension is `rb` not `ru`.